# Is it possible to add a new action to UIUserNotificationCategory after obtaining initial permission?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, ios9

**Background**

- I have an iOS messaging app with an existing, installed userbase.
- I've already asked Users for / obtained system-level Notification permissions (aka, I've called `UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings` with categories / actions).
- [iOS 9 offers a new property on `UIMutableUserNotificationAction` called `behavior` which allows for in-line replies via the `.TextInput` option.](http://thecodeninja.tumblr.com/post/125772843855/notifications-in-ios-9-quick-inline-reply-for)

**Issue**

Upon the release of iOS 9, I want to "upgrade" my Users and support this new "in-line reply" option on push notifications ... but obviously I will first need to **add** a new `UIMutableUserNotificationAction` (with the new behavior property) to each user's `UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()`

**Question**

Since I already have general Notification permissions (badge / sound / alert), can I just, **quietly** re-execute `UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings` and add the new "in-line reply" action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you cannot simply call `UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings` and add a single, new action -- doing that will register **only** the single, new action (and blow away all your others).

Here's what I ended up doing in `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

Note: I use a logic check of `count < 2` because, in previous builds of my app, I'd only established one action in the target category ("REPLY_CATEGORY").

```
// This code ensures that iOS 9 Users (especially iOS 8 ==> iOS 9 upgraders) will be able to see
//  iOS 9's new text input 'behavior', available for notifications quick-actions
if #available(iOS 9, *) {
  if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("asked_for_notification_permission") {
    let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()!

    for category in settings.categories! {
      let cat: UIUserNotificationCategory = category 
      if cat.identifier == "REPLY_CATEGORY" {
        if cat.actionsForContext(UIUserNotificationActionContext.Default)!.count < 2 {
          print("! aD: iOS 9 User has less than the expected reply actions")

          // Re-build entire categories / actions here, including
          //   the new action with .behavior = .TextInput
          // THEN, simply re-register:

          let notificationCategories = NSSet(array: allCategories)
          let settings: UIUserNotificationType = [.Sound, .Alert, .Badge]

          UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: settings, categories: (notificationCategories as! Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>)))

        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Code incomprehensible. If you have comments, format them as comments.